# Laravel Application DDoS Attacked on Shared Server

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5.5

I have been running with some problems with some sites that have been given to me recently, they are consuming A LOT of bandwidth, they are hosted on a shared server, they have been DDoS attacked, but I never have had this issue before, I have been reading but it seems that there's not much I can do (correct me if I'm wrong) since I don't have access to the terminal in that shared server, so it appears the `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.svg|\.mp4|\.woff|\.woff2|\.ttf|\.eot|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|favicon|fonts|videos|storage)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>


<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

1. Is the `.htacess` file alright in order to prevent hackers to write or do tricky stuff inside the root folder or in all the site in general?
2. What can I do to prevent these DDoS attacks?, also, there seems to be the possiblity to write inside the `robots.txt` file the files or folders that I would like to ignore in order to stop google from showing MASSIVE amount of results, but, how will I know the name of the files/folders the hackers are making?
3. I'm using Laravel framework and it seems that the vulnerability is in the root folder and in phpunit vendor's folder.

Comment: Have you considered using something like cloudflare to protect you from DDOS attacks and cache your static files?

Comment: A DDOS is an attack against the network, you should ban those IP addresses in your firewall.  By the time it gets to the application it's already to late to do anything meaningful about it without adversely affecting legitimate users.

Comment: @atymic Didn’t consider it, I will try and test the free plan.

Comment: No worries. I think it's your best option, as it blocks traffic before it hits your server.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Besides the number of results and the amount of bandwidth that the server is consuming, the attack also somehow manage to write some files in the root folder, can I do something about it or my only option is the IP ban?